# How do I get 'rar' package?

Tags: apt, software-installation, repository, rar

I recently installed another Ubuntu after a long time and I'm trying to install `rar` package on it as I use that for compression from within Terminal.

`rar` isn't found when I do

```
apt-get install rar
```

I have even tried doing

```
apt-get update
```

but even after then Ubuntu cannot find `rar`. So how do I get it?

Comment: If you mean compressing with RAR, if you have installed rar and unrar, then all you have to do is right click on folder or file to be compressed and in window select rar.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to enable multiverse repositories to install `rar`. There's also a separate package called `unrar`

To enable multiverse, run

```
sudo software-properties-gtk
```

there you'll need to make sure it is selected.

Then run

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rar
```